# redux-observables mergeMap w/ two outputs

Tags: redux-observable

I have an epic like this

```
/**
 * Request a new account from the API
 */
export function signupApiRequest(action$: Observable, store: Store) {
  return action$.ofType(SIGNUP)
    .map(action => [ action, store.getState().accounts.signup ])
    .mergeMap(([ action, signup ]) =>
      sendCommand('/api/accounts/signup', {
          name: signup.name,
          email: signup.email
        })
        .map(response => [ response, signup.email ])
     )
    .mergeMap(([ response, email ]) => {
      switch (response.status) {
        case 409:
          return [existingUser(email)];

        case 201:
          const succ = { type: successOf(SIGNUP) },
                user = mapTokenToUser(response.body.data),
                created = userCreated(user);
          console.log('signup success', [succ, created]);
          return [succ, created];

        default:
          throw new Error(`Unknown response code ${response.code}`);
      }
    });
}
```

When signing up, 'signup success' is printed and both actions are logged as they should.

However, only the first of the actions is outputted from the epic. [image: Redux actions for realz]

Why and what am I doing wrong?

Changing the order in the array makes the other value get outputted.

Comment: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/263

Answer (score 1):

We've discovered this appears to be a bug in RxJS itself starting in `5.1.0`. There's an exception being thrown in your reducer but it's being swallowed silently by RxJS.

https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/263#issuecomment-310180351

How it's interacting with redux/redux-observable is a little complicated, but ultimately not related as this can be reproduced with:

https://jsbin.com/dukixu/edit?html,js,output

```
const input$ = new Rx.Subject();

input$
  .mergeMap(() => Rx.Observable.of(1, 2))
  .subscribe(d => {
    throw new Error('some error');
  });

input$.next();
```